# Do you know how I can use async await withing a map function to change a variable in every loop?

Tags: javascript, api, async-await, map-function

Do you know how I can make sure that the value of "intentid" change for every loop within the map function? The wanted result is that intentid changes its value for every loop, so that a new value is sent to "someOtherAsyncApiFunction(someinnerfunction())". I need to use async/await, because "intentid2" calls an API.

```
let someobject = {1: {name: "Question"}, 2: {name: "Tipp"}, 3:{name: "Question"}}

intentid = "";

const someFunction = () => {
  Object.keys(someobject).map(async (key,index) =>{
    if (someobject[key].name === "Question") {
      const someinnerfunction = () => {
        let followupintent = intentid;
        return followupintent
      }
      let intentid2 = await someOtherAsyncApiFunction(someinnerfunction())
  
      intentid = intentid2
      console.log(intentid)
    }}
    )
}

someFunction()
```

Comment: And what is the question? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please don't use `.map()`  for simple iteration. You can use a normal loop or `.forEach`. In this particular case, you can also use `.reduce` to create a sequential chain of promises but I'd advise just using a simple `for..of` loop.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek someinnfercuntion() always returns the same value although the api always gives back another value. So the question is how can I make sure that intentid changes for every loop

Answer (score 0):

When you use an `asnyc` mapper function you will get an array of promises.

In order to resolve them, you could use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
const result = await Promise.all(values.map(async x => doSomething(x)))
```